# Why does Google give me different result when I prefix "how to"?

Tags: google-search

Why does Google Search give me different result when I use the prefix "how to" when compared to only using keywords?

For example: I searched "how to lose fat from tummy" and excluded the common keywords "lose fat tummy" without quotes.

I get different results. I thought Google excluded common keywords.

Answer (score 1):

As @danlefree [pointed out](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/22671/4502) in another of your questions, you're referring to stop words, and the situation just isn't that simple anymore. "How to" might be common, but is still important and even interesting from a search perspective, since how-tos are a specific *kind* of article that someone using those terms is probably looking for. So while "some search terms" might get you pages about that topic in general, "**how to** some search terms" may try and specifically weight for tutorials, or at least pages with that phrase in their title/headers.

Comment: So what is best to use - do we target the pre-fix as well in titles and heading or leave it.

Comment: Who is "we?" Target the prefix in what?

Comment: Its my team, I am referring to as "we". I am stuck between these two.

Comment: target the pre-fix in the keywords.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Target whatever it is you're trying to get results for. Are you actually writing how-to articles? If not, then no. The two options probably won't get you wildly different results, anyway; it's a matter of which ones are going to be emphasized.